# jQuery Validation Not Working Properly

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to validate four different fields. The last two have the validation behaving correctly, but the first two don't work (they should only be required). If I press submit without entering anything, only the last two fields show errors.

Here's the jQuery in question:

```
        $("#advertisePost").validate({
            rules: {
                advRetailerName: {
                    required: true
                },
                advName: {
                    required: true
                },
                advPhone: {
                    required: true,
                    phoneUS: true
                },
                advEmail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }           
            },
            messages:{
                advRetailerName: {
                    required: "This is required."
                },
                advName: {
                    required: "This is required."
                },
                advPhone: {
                    required: "This is required.",
                    phoneUS: "This is an invalid phone number."
                },
                advEmail: {
                    required: "This is required",
                    email: "This is an invalid email"
                }
            }
        });
```

Here's the actual form itself:

```
 <form action="php/advertisePost.php" method="POST" id="advertisePost">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Retailer Name</td><td><input type="text" id="advRetailerName" name="advRetailerName" class="required"/><br/><label for="advRetailerName" class="error" generated="true"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Your Name</td><td><input type="text" id="advName" name="advName" class="required"/><br/><label for="advName" class="error" generated="true"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td><td><input type="text" id="advPhone" name="advPhone" class="required"/><br/><label for="advPhone" class="error" generated="true"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email Address</td><td><input type="text" id="advEmail" name="advEmail" class="required"/><br/><label for="advEmail" class="error" generated="true"></label></td>
</tr>
</table>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="advSubmit"/>
</form>
```

I even tried adding the required class to each field. I know it's not a message-handling problem either. The first two fields simply don't follow validation rules. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
      advPhone: {
          required: true,
          phoneUS: true
      },
      advEmail: {
          required: true,
          email: true
      }
});

$("#advertisePost").validate();
```

then add class required to the first two

alternatively you could could just do the validate line and add classes email and required to the last two

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to validate that the first two fields are required then you can set a class = "required" in their respective input fields and set advRetailerName : "required" in your jquery. Here's the documentation for validate: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in validation plugin. Possibly it's not understanding complex-style rule assignment when you're only requesting for "required" parameter? Have you tried the simple way:

```
rules: {
    advRetailerName: "required",
    (...)
}
```